# How to add back button on action bar with more tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-tabs

know anyone how can I add one back button on my action bar? I want to add the back button befor INFO tab. I've try some method but no one of them don't work for me. Well let's start with started.

In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjbTL.jpg) in left part it's what I need to do as actionbar and in the right part it's how looks my project right now.

I've try to put that code for add the back button but it don't works:

```
  actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
  actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Here it's my Activity:
public class TrailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

```
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;
Intent intent;
Trail trail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.trail_fracment_main);

    trail = intent.getParcelableExtra("trail");

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            InfoFragments infoFragments = new InfoFragments();
            infoFragments.setTrail(trail);
            Fragment fragment = infoFragments;
            return fragment;
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new MapFragments();

        } else {
            return new WondersFragments();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Some one told me to try to implement OnBackStackChangedListener and after that he want to put in my code and that:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Listen for changes in the back stack
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    //Handle when activity is recreated like on orientation Change
    shouldDisplayHomeUp();
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    shouldDisplayHomeUp();
}

public void shouldDisplayHomeUp(){
   //Enable Up button only  if there are entries in the back stack
   boolean canback = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0;
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(canback);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    //This method is called when the up button is pressed. Just the pop back stack.
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    return true;
}
```

Also I've try to add and that override method, but again... nothing happen :(

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I've try and that... but again... I've don't obtain any result :(.

So please guys, if anyone know how can I solve that problem, please show me.. I really need to do that and how much fast is possible.

Comment: Eerr... You're not using an action bar.

Comment: im not sure. it should work if you setup a custom toolbar

Comment: I this moment I'm now sure if I've configured it good... If you have any idea how I can make it.. Please tell me, I really need to make it works..